# Writing to a file (internal storage) and sharing it via mail/bluetooth.as a .txt file

Tags: android, email, file-transfer

I've picked up Android only today (so I'm as new to this as it can get) and I'm trying to achieve this:

Let user input some data. Save this data as a .txt file. (in `Internal Storage` since my target phone will not have an SD Card). Read this .txt file and share it as an attachment via mail or share it through any other means. (`Bluetooth/Whatsapp/Facebook/Drive`) etc.

Here is the issue:

I'm able to let the user save the data. I'm also able to read it back. HOWEVER, when I try to share it, it goes as plain text. i.e., if I share it via GMail, it does not go as a text file attachment, rather the text itself goes as the body of the mail. Sharing it via `bluetooth` makes it a .html file, which can still solve my purpose provided it could be sent via mail.

My Code:

Saving data (which comes as a stream of bytes) to file:

```
@Override
public void onReceivedData(byte[] arg0) {
    data = new String(arg0, "UTF-8");
    String filename = "testFile.txt";
    FileOutputStream outputStream;
    try {
        outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_APPEND);
        outputStream.write(data.getBytes());
        //The following 2 lines just for feedback
        data = data.concat(" Wrote to file");
        tvAppend(textView, data);
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Reading from file and sending as attachment:

Approach 1 (which results in plaintext):

```
    char c;
    int i;
    String dataToSend = "";
    String filename = "testFile.txt";
    FileInputStream inputStream;
    try {
        inputStream = openFileInput(filename);
        while((i=inputStream.read())!=-1)
        {
            c=(char)i;
            dataToSend += c;
        }
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, dataToSend);
    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
    startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Approach 2 (which fails to work):

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
try{
    String filePath = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
    File file = new File(filePath, "testFile.txt");
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
}
catch (Exception e)
    e.printStackTrace();
}
sendIntent.setType("*/*");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

In this approach, I get the Share `dialog` box, but all attachments/`bluetooth` transfers fail.

Error messages:

```
Bluetooth: Unknown File; Request can't be handled correctly
```

Gmail Attachment:

```
Permission denied for the attachment
```

Can anyone guide me on this? I did go through the "Note" of the [following](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html#send-binary-content) and also read the documentation pages for `ContentProvider` and `FileProvider` but couldn't get it to work. I tried the "filepaths.xml" approach also but to no use, hence not posting code relevant to that approach.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Thanks in advance.`. Please dont do that. We expect something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 getFilesDir()
```

Delivers path to private internal memory. Reachable for your app only. The mail app has no access.

Use `getExternalFilesDir()` instead. Also when you write the file using FileOutputStream.

On Android 7.0 this will not work either and you have to use a file content provider then.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me. Could you also give me a little insight on using the alternate "File Content Provider" method of writing to file?

Comment: You found the documentation. So show what you tried and tell what does not work. You better start another post with it.